# How to find the radius of the piechart/donut chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a simplest highchart donut chart question. The question I have is what is the default radius of this donut chart. I have not specified the radius anywhere, but seems to have a default radius set somewhere. I could not figure out how this radius was set and was wondering if somebody could help me understand how this radius is set. I did go thru the api reference but could not find this info. Not sure if I missed something.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skumar2013/NVSgL/)

```
$(function () {
 $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            startAngle: 90,
            animation: false,
            innerSize: '60%'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [
            ['Firefox',   44.2],
            ['IE7',       26.6],
            ['IE6',       20],
            ['Chrome',    3.1],
            ['Other',    5.4]
        ]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find out size value using options or API because it seems there is no any for that. It seems that you cannot find it out using for example:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
console.log(chart);
```

and inspecting properties. You will find out that `size` is set to null.

You can find out size inspecting DOM svg elements. To make my job easier I changed option

```
innerSize: 180
```

and find out following svg elements (Note: it is not circle element):

```
...
<path fill="#8bbc21" d="M 532.7575883045118 30.763342348475817 A 140 140 0 0 1 685.1378163408548 95.11881271952285 L 642.2314533619781 120.79066531969326 A 90 90 0 0 0 544.2727353386148 79.41929150973445 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" transform="translate(0,0)" visibility="visible"></path>
<path fill="#910000" d="M 685.2096374472518 95.23898645643143 A 140 140 0 0 1 696.8833100589593 120.0234896156345 L 649.7821278950453 136.8008147529079 A 90 90 0 0 0 642.2776240732333 120.86791986484879 Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round" transform="translate(0,0)" visibility="visible"></path>
...
```

Those are svg path elements which build slices of pie chart donuts. `A 140 140...` and `A 90 90...` are elliptical arc command and 90,90 is rx, ry for inner size, and 140,140 for outer size. So radius is 140 in this case.

I don't know how it is calculated exactly but radius is calculated according to your container size and all different margins, plot borders, spacing... if you do not set size using option `size`.

Comment: Oh this is cool. Thank you so much. Do you happen to know where I could find more explanation about these path elements. I did look at these elements in the chrome developer tools but couldn not figure out what each of them stood for.

Comment: There is a lot of resources about SVG. One is book [SVG Essentials](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have a radius option it seems. But there is an option:

> width: Number
>   An explicit width for the chart. By default the width is calculated from the offset width of the containing element.
>   Try it: 800px wide

Refer to this [link](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.width)

Answer (score 1):

No radius option, but [there is a diameter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size).  You can express it in pixels (given by number) or as a percent of the chart area (give as string `'N%'`):

> size: String|Number The diameter of the pie relative to the plot area.
>   Can be a percentage or pixel value. Pixel values are given as
>   integers. The default behaviour (as of 3.0) is to scale to the plot
>   area and give room for data labels within the plot area. As a
>   consequence, the size of the pie may vary when points are updated and
>   data labels more around. In that case it is best to set a fixed value,
>   for example "75%". Defaults to .

[Here's your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NVSgL/1/) with the pie chart 150% of the chart area.